# certbot cannot import name 'appengine' from 'urllib3.contrib'

Tags: ubuntu, certbot, python-3.10

On my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with Python 3.10.6, Certbot gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_toolbelt/_compat.py", line 48, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib import appengine as gaecontrib
ImportError: cannot import name 'appengine' from 'requests.packages.urllib3.contrib' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/__init__.py)
```

with the complete error message:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('certbot==1.21.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')())
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from certbot._internal import main as internal_main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/_internal/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    from certbot._internal import account
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/_internal/account.py", line 19, in <module>
    from acme.client import ClientBase  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/acme/client.py", line 34, in <module>
    from requests_toolbelt.adapters.source import SourceAddressAdapter
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_toolbelt/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .adapters import SSLAdapter, SourceAddressAdapter
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_toolbelt/adapters/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .ssl import SSLAdapter
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_toolbelt/adapters/ssl.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .._compat import poolmanager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_toolbelt/_compat.py", line 50, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import appengine as gaecontrib
ImportError: cannot import name 'appengine' from 'urllib3.contrib' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/__init__.py)
```

It's kind of a lot errors and I don't know where to start to resolve it.
I little help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 21):

urllib3 was installed by both apt and pip. I removed the pip version by issuing:

```
pip3 uninstall urllib3
```

Now certbot work fine.

Comment: If you're using packages that usually install via `pip3`, `pipx` at https://pipx.pypa.io/ may be a better way forward in most cases.

Comment: I did this but then I get ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'```. I'm running my script from a venv..